# Reputations per view of a question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Will it be better if a user gets some reputations for views of his question.

Comment: At least when nobody is answers till then the reputations should be increased so that one may place a bounty of that many reputations

Comment: No. Never. It's totally a blemish. Why the hell would rep depend on number of views? Upvoting depends on the quality of the post and not just how many peeped into it.'

Comment: @user36790 but there are so many people who do not answer a question if it is not having any votes for example see any question with many upvotes you would find many answers for it but questions with 0 or 1 upvotes will get only 1 answer , many people do not answer questions which are in depth so they just view it and do not upvotes it

Comment: Consider my question only there is one downvote although I only gave suggestion shouldn't even this question be upvoted?

Comment: Downvotes in meta does mean that the user is not in consent with your suggestion; that's it.

Comment: In other words, for something like this, upvotes and downvotes can indicate whether people agree with your suggestion. A downvote doesn't necessarily mean it's a bad post.

Comment: @David Then why do reputations get deducted on main site per downvote

Comment: Because on the main site, downvotes _do_ indicate that people think the post is bad. It's only on meta, and only for suggestion posts (somewhat broadly defined), that the rule from user36790's comment applies.

Comment: There [are](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/48/popular-question) [already](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/47/notable-question) [incentives](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/37/famous-question) to reward questions with high views. Feature requests like this are often best posed at [meta.se], where there are more people able to comment on why the system, as it is, works well.

Comment: Probably related: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/7269/

Answer (score 7):

Consider a really bad question. It takes at least 5 users to vote to close it, which means 5 people looked at it. Should somebody get rep just because the first 5 people voted to close the question?

Maybe it's borderline and 30 people look at it before it collects 5 votes to close. Or maybe 100 people look at it and think it's off-topic but they don't have the rep to close it as such. Should rep be awarded on those views?

Let's say I write a bot that scans the site looking for who knows what, but it loads every question page. Each time I scan it, it increments the view count on the question. Should rep be awarded then?

Those are just the first examples that came to mind. Reputation needs to be something reliable and needs to be a measure of quality, not a measure of popularity. If a question is bad, it gets downvoted. If it is good, it gets upvoted. If nobody sees it because it is very narrow or very uninteresting, well, try to make it less narrow or try to make it more interesting. In the end, if you want rep, just make better questions that are well done and provide a challenge people want to take on by answering.

If you solve that problem, then views will come and rep will come. Start the beginning and build a good foundation.